# Kotlin How to extend using secondary constructor

Tags: kotlin

I have a helper class to get network updates. When i try to create secondary constructor it throw error
based on documentation in kotlin i need to extend super class. But i get the same error. 
As per documentation ConnectivityManager does not have constructor

I get this error

```
Supertype initialization is impossible without primary constructor
```

My helper class

```
class InternetConnectivityHelper : ConnectivityManager.NetworkCallback() {

    constructor(context: Context, internetStatusChangedListener: InternetStatusChangedListener): super(){

    }
}
```

I also tried based on one of stackoverflow answer

```
class InternetConnectivityHelper : ConnectivityManager.NetworkCallback() {

    constructor(context: Context, internetStatusChangedListener: InternetStatusChangedListener): this(){

    }
}
```

I also watch this tutorial but cant seem to get it to work 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DmSLv-fX8PA&list=PLlxmoA0rQ-LwgK1JsnMsakYNACYGa1cjR&index=40

Comment: That code works for me. It is your own code (that you didn't share)  that crashes.

Comment: @Enselic I updated my question. I think i need a way to check the null value

Comment: I am also getting list of all the permissions without any crash.

Comment: You should check an official documentation about null-safety https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/null-safety.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is that `requestedPermissions` can be null according to the documentation.

```
/**
 * Array of all {@link android.R.styleable#AndroidManifestUsesPermission
 * &lt;uses-permission&gt;} tags included under &lt;manifest&gt;,
 * or null if there were none.  This is only filled in if the flag
 * {@link PackageManager#GET_PERMISSIONS} was set.  This list includes
 * all permissions requested, even those that were not granted or known
 * by the system at install time.
 */
public String[] requestedPermissions;
```

But your `permissionList` variable is null-safe - you cannot assign null to a null-safe variable.

UPD: try using this code (added null check and replaced an array with a list)

```
object RuntimePermissionUtil {
private var permissionList = mutableListOf<String>()

fun retrivePermissionList(context: Context) : List<String>{

    context.getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(context.packageName, PackageManager.GET_PERMISSIONS).requestedPermissions?.let {
        permissionList.clear()
        permissionList.addAll(it)
    }

    //your other stuff

    return permissionList
}
}
```

Comment: How do i check if requestedPermissions is null? ... do i use if(requestedPermissions != null){} .. actually i think this is the issue. I dont have permissions list yet. And as i learnt kotlin will throw error on null too if i dont manage it

Comment: You should use `?.` operator to deal with nullable variables. Updated my answer

Answer (score 0):

I manage to solve it by initialising the value as below

```
object RuntimePermissionUtil {

    private var permissionList : Array<String> = emptyArray()

    fun RetrivePermissionList(context: Context) : Array<String>{

        if(context.packageManager.getPackageInfo(context.packageName, PackageManager.GET_PERMISSIONS).requestedPermissions != null){
            permissionList = context.packageManager.getPackageInfo(context.packageName, PackageManager.GET_PERMISSIONS).requestedPermissions
        }

        if(LogConfiguration.RuntimePermissionEnabled){
            LogUtil.LOGD(LogConfiguration.RuntimePermission, "RetrievePermissionList : "+ permissionList.contentToString())
        }

        return permissionList
    }
}
```